# Flutter Web: ClipPath widget not working on web on iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-web

I have an application that needs to use the ClipPath widget so I can define a custom path.

I have the following code for the custom clipper:

```
class RectClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {

  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width / 2, size.height);
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height - 100);
    path.lineTo(size.width, 0);
    path.close();
    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) => true;
}
```

An this code where I apply the clipper to the image

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: RectClipper(),
  clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
  child: Image.network("https://source.unsplash.com/user/erondu/800x500"),
),
```

So based on this code, this is what I can see on the web on my Mac or Windows, as well as in the iOS and Android apps:

[No issue on web on desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyhyl.jpg)

However, on web - Safari, Chrome and Firefox, on iOS, the ClipPath widget does not seem to work:

[Issue on web on iOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbjhw.png)

I have tested the other Clip widgets e.g. ClipRect and ClipOval, and they seem work just fine.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: what [--web-renderer](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/web-renderers) are you using when running / building  your flutter web app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi @pskink, I think I use the default one, as in HTML when on mobile web and CanvasKit when on the desktop web, since I just debug the app from VS code.

Comment: and what about `CanvasKit` ? does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works just fine. The only issue I can see now is that it would make the website havier which will slow down the site I believe. Do you think there is any workaround?

Comment: from my experience it slows down only in initial load, later it uses the cached renderer

Comment: Thank you for your help @pskink. Then I will just need to let the app work with it for a while and see whether it is going to be an issue or not.

Thanks again!

Comment: sure, your welcome